# Laravel eloquent not fetching the data properly

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, relationship

In my laravel vue application I have two tables, `user` table and `user_document` table.

In my `user_document` table, I have a column called, `added_by`.

This column stores the  `id`s of the users.

There are two roles in my app, admins and general users.

My users can upload documents to the system via vue component. Admin can upload documents for other users as well.

And users can view their already uploaded document details in a datatable.

In that datatable, I'm displaying a column called, `Added By`, which shows the users who uploaded the document(the user him self or by the admin).

I have following controller to fetch and display those records.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Corporate\Employee;

use App\Company;
use App\Models\OtherDocument;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CompanyEmployeeOtherDocumentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param string $locale
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(string $locale, Company $company, User $user)
    {

        $otherDocuments = OtherDocument::where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->with('added_by_user')
            ->when(request('validity_status'), function ($query) {
                $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->when( in_array('active', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->where(function (Builder $query) {
                            $query->whereDate('issued_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
                                ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->addMonth());
                        })->orWhere('is_valid_forever',1);
                    })->when( in_array('expires', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->orWhere(function (Builder $query) {
                            $query->whereDate('expires_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->addMonth())
                                ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now());
                        });
                    })->when( in_array('expired', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->orWhereDate('expires_at', '<', Carbon::now());
                    });
                });
            })
            ->when(request('search_text'), function ($query) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . request('search_text') . '%');
            })
            ->paginate(request('per_page',config('statguru.pagination.limit')));

        for ($i=0; $i < count($otherDocuments); $i++) {
            $addedByUser = $otherDocuments[$i]->added_by_user;
            if ($addedByUser) {
                $otherDocuments[$i]['added_user_name'] = $addedByUser->first_name . ' ' . $addedByUser->last_name;
            }
        }

        return  response()->json($otherDocuments);

    }
}
```

And in my vue component I have following header array,

```
HeaderArray() {
            return [
                {text: 'Certificate', value: 'certificate'},
                {text: 'Added by', value: 'added_by_user_name'},
                {text: 'Institute', value: 'institute'},
                {text: 'Expiration', value: 'valid_date', classList: 'text-center'},
                {text: 'Validity', value: 'validity_status', classList: 'text-center'},
                {text: 'Verification', value: 'verification_status', classList: 'text-center'},
            ];
        },
```

**This whole solution works perfectly.**

But now instead of using this for loop

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($otherDocuments); $i++) {
                $addedByUser = $otherDocuments[$i]->added_by_user;
                if ($addedByUser) {
                    $otherDocuments[$i]['added_user_name'] = $addedByUser->first_name . ' ' . $addedByUser->last_name;
                }
            }
```

I'm trying to get the same result via eloquent

```
->with(['added_by_user' => function($q){
                $q->select('first_name', 'last_name');
             }])
```

When I replace the for loop with this, it does not show me the Added by user's first name.... Where do I need to change in the eloquent to fetch that data correctly?

I'm using laravel 9

**Update**

I have updated my code according to the Malkhazi Dartsmelidze answer below.

Yet I am not being able to display the name on the datatable.

Following is my updated controller,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Corporate\Employee;

use App\Company;
use App\Models\OtherDocument;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CompanyEmployeeOtherDocumentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param string $locale
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(string $locale, Company $company, User $user)
    {

        $otherDocuments = OtherDocument::where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->with(['added_by_user' => function($q){
            $q->select('id', DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) as added_user_name'));
        }]) 
            ->when(request('validity_status'), function ($query) {
                $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->when( in_array('active', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->where(function (Builder $query) {
                            $query->whereDate('issued_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
                                ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->addMonth());
                        })->orWhere('is_valid_forever',1);
                    })->when( in_array('expires', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->orWhere(function (Builder $query) {
                            $query->whereDate('expires_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->addMonth())
                                ->whereDate('expires_at', '>=', Carbon::now());
                        });
                    })->when( in_array('expired', request('validity_status')), function ($query) {
                        $query->orWhereDate('expires_at', '<', Carbon::now());
                    });
                });
            })
            ->when(request('search_text'), function ($query) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . request('search_text') . '%');
            })

            ->paginate(request('per_page',config('statguru.pagination.limit')));

        return  response()->json($otherDocuments);

    }
}
```

and following is the vue header array,

```
 HeaderArray() {
            return [
                {text: 'Certificate', value: 'certificate'},
                {text: 'Added by', value: 'added_user_name'},
                {text: 'Institute', value: 'institute'},
                {text: 'Expiration', value: 'valid_date', classList: 'text-center'},
                {text: 'Validity', value: 'validity_status', classList: 'text-center'},
                {text: 'Verification', value: 'verification_status', classList: 'text-center'},
            ];
        },
```

And following is the data I recieve

```
{
      "id": 6,
      "user_id": 941,
      "added_by": 869,
      "name": "driving licence",
      "issued_at": "2022-04-06T22:00:00.000000Z",
      "expires_at": "2022-04-29T22:00:00.000000Z",
      "is_valid_forever": 0,
      "document_url": null,
      "document_number": null,
      "file_name": "6-driving-licence.pdf",
      "url": "users/941/other-documents/6-driving-licence.pdf",
      "status": "EXPIRES",
      "created_at": "2022-04-07T03:39:47.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-07T03:39:47.000000Z",
      "deleted_at": null,
      "expires_at_formatted": "30-04-2022",
      "validity_status": "EXPIRES",
      "remaining_days": 18,
      "added_by_user": {
        "id": 869,
        "added_user_name": "Satya Nadella",
        "country_code": null,
        "formatted_date_of_birth": "2022-04-11",
        "name": " ",
        "company_role": "admin",
        "profile_image": [
          {
            "url": "/img/statguru-user.png"
          }
        ],
        "inviter_user": "",
        "country": null,
        "media": [
          
        ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: Could you please log the query they are returning. Wrap your query using: `\DB::enableQueryLog()` and `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong here:

```
->with(['added_by_user' => function($q){
    $q->select('first_name', 'last_name');
}])
```

The way relationship is working is that laravel loops trough result of that query and matches `users.id` to `user_documents.added_by` each other and if matches then attaches it.

Since you have selected only `first_name` and `last_name` columns, `id` of it always is `null` and not matches any `user_documents`.

#### Solution:

```
->with(['added_by_user' => function($q){
    $q->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
}])
```

##### More convenient way to get full name:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
...
->with(['added_by_user' => function($q){
    $q->select('id', DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) as added_user_name'));
}])
```

## Edit:

Since front end requres that `added_user_name` should be in the first level of object, you should either map through results and move `added_user_name` to first level, or join `users` table and get result from it:
But if you are using pagination it's not recommended to use `map` solution. I'll write only using join

###### Using `join`:

Remove `->with` function from query and replace it with `join`.

```
OtherDocument::where('user_id', $user->id)
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_document.added_by') // do not know exact names of columns
    ->select(DB::raw('user_document.*'), DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) as added_user_name'))
    ->...
```

Comment: thank you for the perfect explanation and the solution, but still the user name does not appear on my datatable

Comment: Glad to help you.
You have `added_by_user_name`  as header key in vuejs file and in php code you have `added_user_name` . Change one of them to match each other

Comment: I tried changing the vue header array as well, but yet am not able to display the name, so my current vue header is {text: 'Added by', value: 'added_by_user'},.....

Comment: Try changing it to: added_user_name

Comment: nope it's not working either, please let me update the question with the array i'm getting

Comment: Oh, I see. `added_by_user` is returned as object and that's why it doesn't work. Check if your front table can access nested property like this: `added_by_user.added_user_name`. Let me know and I'll update answer

Comment: no, tried using added_by_user.added_user_name, still shows nothing...

Comment: Then I'll edit answer with two solutions again :D

Comment: Edited answer and changed it with join.